# How to match the last segment of the URL (string)?

Tags: php, regex

I want to add/replace the last segment of the url *(regardless url parameters)* with `en`.

- If last segment isn't either `en` or `fa`, then add `en` as last segment.
- If last segment is either `en` or `fa`, then replace it with `en`.

---

#### Here is four examples:

**One:**

```
$str = 'http://localhost:8000/search/fa?q=sth';
```

expected output:

```
//=>    http://localhost:8000/search/en?q=sth
```

**Two:**

```
$str = 'http://localhost:8000/search?q=sth';
```

expected output:

```
//=>    http://localhost:8000/search/en?q=sth
```

**Three:**

```
$str = 'http://localhost:8000/search';
```

expected output:

```
//=>    http://localhost:8000/search/en
```

**Four:**

```
$str = 'http://localhost:8000/search/fa';
```

expected output:

```
//=>    http://localhost:8000/search/en
```

---

Also here is what I've tried so far:

```
/\/(?:en|fa)(?=\??)/
```

php version:

```
preg_replace('/\/(?:en|fa)(?=\??)/', '/en', Request::fullUrl())
```

As you see, my pattern depends on `en`, `fa` keywords and it fails when there isn't none of them.

Answer (score 1):

Split url to individual components with [parse-url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php), manipulate path, and compile it back:

```
$str = 'http://localhost:8000/search/fa?q=sth';

$parts = parse_url($str);

//play with the last part of the path:
$path = explode('/', $parts['path']);
$last = array_pop($path);
if (!in_array($last, ['en','fa'])) {        
    $path[] = $last;
}
$path[]='en';

//compile url
$result = "";
if (!empty($parts['scheme'])) {
    $result .= $parts['scheme'] . "://";
}
if (!empty($parts['host'])) {
    $result .= $parts['host'];
}
if (!empty($parts['port'])) {
    $result .= ":" . $parts['port'];
}
if (!empty($path)) {
    $result .= implode('/', $path);
}
if (!empty($parts['query'])) {
    $result .= '?' . $parts['query'];
}

echo $result;
```

[Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d29ce5a7733274078d5d24a2094f0afddf084c78)